# После перехода с Qt 5.4.2 на Qt 5.5.1 перестал отображаться WebView

Tags: qt, qml

После перехода с Qt 5.4.2 на Qt 5.5.1 перестал отображаться WebView (под андроидом и под айосом). Заметили не сразу. Откатываться не хочется. Может есть какой-то нюанс, позволяющий вернуть WebView в работоспособное состояние? Для уверенности собрал с qt 5.4.2 - WebView отображается.

сейчас так:

```
Rectangle {
        id: idWebViewParent
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            topMargin: idHeader.height
        }
        color: "yellow"

        WebView {
            id: idWebView
            url: "http://www.yandex.ru/m/"  
            onUrlChanged: {
                console.log("WebView.onUrlChanged: ", url);
            }

            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("WebView.onCompleted url: " + url)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что в main.qml WebView работает, если разместить его на ApplicationWindow

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtWebView 1.0
...

ApplicationWindow {
...
...
    WebView {
        id: loginWebView
        visible: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        onUrlChanged: {
            console.log("loginWebView.onUrlChanged: ", url);
        }
    }
}
```